# Configuring static files in Django in production

Tags: django

I'm having difficulty configuring static files in Django 2.0.3 The production server deployed on Heroku works properly when DEBUG = True, but as soon as I switch it to DEBUG = False, I get an Application error, spawning 9 identical ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error emails.

Further confounding me, is that the local dev server is set to DEBUG = True, yet the paths to my static files using href="{% static "images/apple-icon-57x57.png" %}" show the full path to Amazon S3 href="https://r2cp-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/apple-icon-57x57.png". I thought that DEBUG = True would serve static files from my local server? Setting DEBUG = False on the local dev server does not cause any problems.

I'm using storages.backends.s3boto3 for both static and media storage.

Running Collectstatic doesn't return any errors. Is there something that's causing a problem with the creation of a manifest entry?

I've tried with and without setting STATIC_ROOT.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Here's the text of the error message from the prod server when DEBUG = False.

```
Internal Server Error: /

ValueError at /
Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://obscure-lake-48617.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Executable: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path: ['/app', '/app/.heroku/python/bin', '/app', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/app/r2cp', '/app/r2cp/apps']
Server time: Sun, 8 Apr 2018 17:22:58 -0400
Installed Applications:
('admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'imagekit',
 'storages',
 'main')
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/r2cp/apps/main/views.py" in home
  51.         'overview': overview

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

During handling of the above exception (Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'), another exception occurred:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  95.             response = self.get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  37.             response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in response_for_exception
  87.         response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in handle_uncaught_exception
  126.     return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py" in server_error
  75.     return HttpResponseServerError(template.render())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

During handling of the above exception (Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'), another exception occurred:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  95.             response = self.get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  37.             response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in response_for_exception
  87.         response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in handle_uncaught_exception
  126.     return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py" in server_error
  75.     return HttpResponseServerError(template.render())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

During handling of the above exception (Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'), another exception occurred:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  95.             response = self.get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  37.             response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in response_for_exception
  87.         response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in handle_uncaught_exception
  126.     return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py" in server_error
  75.     return HttpResponseServerError(template.render())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

During handling of the above exception (Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'), another exception occurred:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  95.             response = self.get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  37.             response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in response_for_exception
  87.         response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in handle_uncaught_exception
  126.     return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py" in server_error
  75.     return HttpResponseServerError(template.render())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

During handling of the above exception (Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'), another exception occurred:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  95.             response = self.get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  37.             response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in response_for_exception
  87.         response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in handle_uncaught_exception
  126.     return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py" in server_error
  75.     return HttpResponseServerError(template.render())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/apple-icon-57x57.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually solved my problem. I suspect the issue is that running collectstatic from the command line is spinning up a separate dyno in Heroku and the files go away once that dyno ends. I had disabled collectstatic in the Heroku settings for my app, and it appears that deleting this config and letting the build process run collectstatic fixed everything.